# Log cat don't show log's

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm working on android . it seem's that some times my LogCat doesn't work correctly and do not any thing mean that it don't show any thing . (specialy when i working on more than one emulator .) can any one help me ?I need my LogCat .

Comment: You could have a problem with filtering, device selection, or IDE/plugin bugs.  Try it from the command line, and learn to use the -s option to specify the emulator of interest.

Comment: can you guide me how to do that ?

Comment: no . i didn't use filtering and i have checked it.

Comment: run ddms it usually shows everything well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it happens when eclipse loses the connection to the adb server. The cause is often testing on more devices/emulators.

In order to fix this, open the DDMS perspective and in the Devices View click on the device for which you want to output the logs in LogCat and they will appear again.

In Eclipse:

**Window > Open Perspective > DDMS, then
click on the device in the "Devices" view**

Or if you do not want to switch perspectives
Window > Show View > Other
select -> Android > Devices

Answer (score 0):

Might be an filtering issue in eclipse...clear filters and set mode to verbose!

Answer (score 0):

A few items to try:

1. Make sure your USB Debugging is enabled.
2. Make sure you have the right drivers for your phone installed - you can usually get them from the manufacturer's website. These are *not always* the same as the drivers installed by Windows for media sharing. [This site](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers) will help for finding OEM USB drivers.
3. Close the LogCat window. Connect your device. Make sure USB debugging is enabled. Re-open LogCat.
4. Make sure you're in the right view in LogCat. You may be in an app filter view and not the un-filtered view.
5. Restart Eclipse and try any of #1 - #4.

Good luck!