# Logs display nothing in Logcat and DDMS has no devices?

Tags: android, logging, logcat, android-logcat

When running the App. the `Logs` I use do not show any output. Also, I referred to [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496777/log-cat-dont-show-logs) but I found there is no devices are listed in the `DDMS`. Any suggestions?

***Update***

I am working on Windows OS. And test my Apps. on Galaxy Note_3

Kies driver is installed and the Developers options are enabled

Comment: update your driver before that uninstall your old driver

Comment: @IllegalArgument would you please tell me how to update the driver?

Comment: are you using windows?? whats the model of your device??

Comment: @IllegalArgument yes i am using windows OS. And I test my Apps on Galaxy Note3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) check whether your device is connected in USB Debugging mode

2) install USB driver

3) `adb device` if this does not show you your  device  then go to   [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469646/adb-devices-cant-find-my-phone)

Comment: would you please tell me what is `adb`?

Comment: should i write `adb kill-server` in the `cmd`?

Comment: yes first `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`

Comment: it tells me that `adb` is not recognised

Comment: go to you ADT directory the type `cd sdk/platform-tools` then run that command

Answer (score 0):

You should install your android device's driver to your PC/MAC correctly. And also you have to activate your  android device's USB Debugging Mode in Developer Options menu under Settings.

Comment: yes, Kies driver is installed and the developers options of the device are activated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have drivers for Galaxy Note_3 installed on your machine, once it's there DDMS will automatically detect the device, if not then try to reset your ADB from eclipse,  even if doesn't detect then restart eclipse.

Comment: as mentioned in the update, kies driver is installed. logcat was showing output but unexpectedly it shows nothing now even after restarting eclipse

Comment: @Elpharaoh Did you try resetting the adb from eclipse or you can use command line and type **adb kill-server** and then immediately **adb start-server**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Unplug device from computer.
2. Unlock device.
3. Plug device into computer while unlocked (lockscreen).

On the device you will then be prompted to allow the computer to connect. I have a note 3 and in my experience I do not get this prompt if I plug it in while it is still locked. Testing it now I see nothing in DDMS when done this way. Although sometimes it will show something listed but say [Offline].